# how to create a json object and parse it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In the 'create' action for my instance model, I have:

```
@my_json_page = {}
@my_json_page["title"] = params[:title].to_json
@my_json_page["headline"] = params[:headline].to_json
@instance.profile_page_json = @my_json_page
```

And in the 'edit' action, I try to parse it:

```
@parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@instance.profile_page_json)
```

And in the edit view, I get the 'title field':

```
%input{:type=>"text", :value=>@parsed_json["title"],:name=>"title", :style=>"width: 815px;"}
```

And it says "MultiJson::LoadError (795: unexpected token at '--- "

I am not sure how I should create the json object to later parse it conveniently. I am probably doing it wrong. Would really appreciate if someone could guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've understood what for do You need this, but

```
@instance.profile_page_json = {"title" => params[:title], "headline" => params[:headline]}.to_json
```

in the 'create' action should help You.

But IMHO the best way will be to save the params hash without encoding to the variable and get it from the view. Like this:

```
#in the controller
@parsed_json = params

#in the view
%input{:type=>"text", :value=>@parsed_json["title"],:name=>"title", :style=>"width: 815px;"}
```

And You can even try to get access to the params method directly from the view (not sure, but You can try anyway)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I forgot to say I save it to the database and try to parse it to get those 2 fields again. So, it worked after decoding it as:     @parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@instance._profile_page_json)